# How can I remove the last button added with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I've added this code to Form3 to create a new button on Form2:

```
Dim bt As New Button
bt.Text = Annen.Text
bt.Name = Annen.Text
bt.Location = New Point(8, 15 + Form2.sira * 24)
AddHandler bt.Click, AddressOf Form2.tıkla
Form2.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(bt)
Hide()
```

(`Form2.sira` is an integer that increases 1 everytime)

I need to add a button to Form2 to delete the last button added, how could I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you would remove the last control added to your flow layout panel

```
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1).Dispose()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: RemoveAt doesn't dispose the control.  You can directly dispose of it and it will be removed: `FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1).Dispose()`

Comment: Disposing is incredibly important otherwise you can lock up valuable system resources causing the program to crash.